# How to find the LAST (repetitive) value in a range using a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

For example I have the following data starting in cell 'B3' :

1. B3    qqq
2. B4    www
3. B5    eee
4. B6    qqq
5. B7    qqq
6. B8    rrr

I want to loop through the whole range "B:B" and find and stop at the cell address of the **LAST** "qqq" that is present in that range (In this case "qqq" in range "B7")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will Work for you :

```
Sub rep()

Dim c As Range
Dim add As String
Dim add1 As String

With ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
    Set c = .Find("qqq", LookIn:=xlValues) ' change qqq with other string or Userform Input variable
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        add = c.Address
        Do
            add1 = c.Address
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If c.Address = add Then GoTo E
        Loop
        End If
End With

E:

MsgBox add1

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd remove the `GoTo` and use either `Exit Do` or `Loop until c.Address = add`. Think the syntax is correct - haven't checked.

Comment: On second thoughts `FindPrevious` would find the last occurance.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook .. I have tried it.. It works :) Though your suggestions are right.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code using `Dictionary` (you need to add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime by going to Tools->References from the menu)

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindLastOccurenceOfRepepetiveValue()
    Dim dict As Dictionary, lastRow As Long, i As Long, val As String
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        val = Cells(i, 2).Value
        If dict.Exists(val) Then
            dict(val) = dict(val) + 1
        Else
            dict(val) = 1
        End If
    Next

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If dict(Cells(i, 2).Value) > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Repetetive value found"
            Cells(i, 2).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim SearchValue As String

    'Change this to get the value from the userform
    SearchValue = "qqq"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column B
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        'Create an array with all the values
        arr = .Range("B3:B" & LastRow).Value
        'Loop array
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'If there is a match
            If arr(i, 1) = SearchValue Then
                Set rngFound = .Range("B" & i + 2)

            End If

        Next i

        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The last cell value " & SearchValue & " found is :" & rngFound.Address
        Else
            MsgBox "Value not found."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```